# White lines in gradient.rect from R's plotrix package

Tags: r, colors, rstudio, gradient, plotrix

Anybody have a solution for removing the white lines seen here in the graduated rectangles at the top of the plot? These are produced with `gradient.rect` from the `plotrix` package.

```
gradient.rect(as.Date("1979-05-04"),70,as.Date("1990-11-28"),80,col=smoothColors("royalblue",100.0,"white"),border=NA,gradient="x")
```

They appear both in the output from RStudio and in the exported PNG.

[image: R base plot with graduated color rectangles]

Comment: Such artifacts are sometimes caused by the viewer although they are usually more regular and happens with the pdf format.You should post full code and data to reproduce.

Comment: Load into a graphics packages (gimp or photoshop) and zoom in to see if they are really there or artefacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the problem (although not that image) with this code:

```
png();plot(x=seq(as.Date("1979-05-04"),as.Date("1990-11-28"),length=50),
           1:50,type="n",axes=FALSE)  # set up plot coords correctly
plotrix::gradient.rect(as.Date("1979-05-04"),5, as.Date("1990-11-28"),6, 
                      col=plotrix::smoothColors("royalblue", 100.0,"white"), 
                      border=NA,gradient="x",nslices=121); 
dev.off()
```

Then I saw three thin, white vertical bands. I looked at the RGB values and plotted their hexadecimal equivalents:

```
plot(NA, xlim=c(1,110),ylim=c(0x4169E1, 0xFFFFFF) )
lines(1:102, as.numeric(
              paste0('0x', 
                     substr( plotrix::smoothColors("royalblue",100.0,"white"),
                             2,7)
                    ) ) )
```

I noticed that there were uneven gaps in the sequences so tried using smaller number of colors with better success:

```
png(); plot(x=seq(as.Date("1979-05-04"),as.Date("1990-11-28"),length=50),1:50,type="n",axes=FALSE)
plotrix::gradient.rect(as.Date("1979-05-04"),20,as.Date("1990-11-28"),30,
       col=plotrix::smoothColors("royalblue",55,"white"),border=NA,gradient="x");dev.off()
```

[image]

I don't really understand why this happens. You might contact Jim Lemon if you need an explanation ... rather than just a fix strategy. His email address should appear at your R console if you type: `maintainer("plotrix")`

Comment: Yes, it seems that playing around with the number of colors makes the white lines move, and with enough tinkering, go away. Thank you.